# FME Combine Values

Tags: attribute-table, fme-form, classification

I am new in FME and have a table with 10 columns. Every column contains different values.

I want to create a new column, that assigns a name to each unique row of data. So, for every unique combination of the values in the four columns below, there is a specific name.

That means I want to create classes from the other values.

[image: example]

Here is a short example. I have 4 columns. The new column is based on the combination of other columns. If `a=12`, `b=1`, `c=41` and `d=Alpha` then the `new Value = Object 1` and so on.

Which is the best transformer for my task?

Comment: Just to clear the confusion. By analysing the values in the first 4 colums you would like to get the value from column 5 as a result right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the "Tester" in series for all to set all the conditions in a raw (a feature as we call it) followed by the "AttributeCreator"
You can change the Pass Criteria for the Tester from "Or" to "And"

[image: Tester Transformer]

[image: AttributeCreator Transformer]

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will test your way. But I could solve my problem with the "conditional value" of the attribute manager.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @buddiebubba is a good way to go; but I'll post another method anyway.

Add a Deaggregator transformer and use your combination of attributes for the group-by setting. Set a List name:

[image]

Now add a Counter to create an ID number, plus a Deaggregator:

[image]

That basically gives you a unique ID for each set of values using a single transformer. It's just a number though, so if you want Object 1, Object 2, etc instead of 1, 2, 3, etc then you can use a StringConcatenator to add "Object " as a prefix to each value.

Then you don't need to do the FeatureMerging, or filter out unique combinations. Just be careful with the Aggregator/Deaggregator parameters to ensure you get the right attributes.

Comment: This solution is faster as well.

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly: There are multiple ways to do this but one way is:

- Sampler to get one feature of every combination. (Group by a,b,c,d.)
- Counter to give every combination a unique number.
- AttributeCreator to create the "new Value" attribute.
- FeatureMerger to add the combinations to the data. (Requestor/Supplier a,b,c,d)

[image: FME Desktop 2018.1 Workbench]

[image: FME Desktop 2018.1 Inspector]